# Round robin scheduling in matlab

Tags: matlab, round-robin

```
clear all
close all
no_of_processors=5;
task_matrix=zeros(no_of_processors,3);
for i=1:no_of_processors
Burst_time=randi(20);
% Priority = minValue + (maxValue-minValue)*randi(5);
Priority=randi(5);``
task_matrix(i,:)=[i Burst_time Priority];
end



disp('Processors   Burst_time  Priority');
disp('....................................');
disp(task_matrix);
```

This is my code to generate random burst time and priority and the thing here is I get random priority which is repeating. I need the priority which should not repeat. can anyone help me in this.? And can anyone help me with initiating a time quantum?

Comment: I used randperm but that didn't help when it comes to this line "task_matrix(i,:)=[i Burst_time Priority];" it shows the error as Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
rng('shuffle');
```

before randomizing

**rng(sd)** seeds the random number generator using the nonnegative integer **sd** so that **rand**, **randi**, and **randn** produce a predictable sequence of numbers.

**rng('shuffle')** seeds the random number generator based on the current time so that rand, **randi**, and **randn** produce a different sequence of numbers after each time you call **rng**.

Answer (score 0):

```
randperm(no_of_processors)
```

Creates a random permutation of the numbers 1 to 5, which avoids repeating values.

Comment: Yes I did that but when  it comes to this line "task_matrix(i,:)=[i Burst_time Priority];" it shows the error as Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: `priorities=randperm(no_of_processors)` generates a vector with the priority for all five processors, you have to use `priorities(i)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but then too am getting the same repeating priorities.

Comment: How did you get repeating values? The output of randperm is unique. As long as you use one random permutation, it should be impossible to get repeating values.

Comment: yes its not repeating but when it comes to the next line task_matrix(i,:)=[i Burst_time(i) Priority(i)]; it is repeating

Comment: clear all;
close all;
no_of_processors=5;
task_matrix=zeros(no_of_processors,3);
for i=1:no_of_processors
Burst_time=randperm(20);
Priority=randperm(no_of_processors);
task_matrix(i,:)=[i Burst_time(i) Priority(i)];
end

disp('Processors   Burst_time  Priority');
disp('....................................');
disp(task_matrix);

Comment: You are generating multiple independent permutations, thus repetitions are possible. Generate the permutation once outside the loop.